# Android 13 AOSP building can not flash image

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to build Android 13 and flash it to my device, Pixel 3a.

I followed the documentation, https://source.android.com/docs/setup/start and https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building.

```
mkdir aosp
cd aosp
git config --global user.name Your Name
git config --global user.email you@example.com
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-13.0.0_r50

repo sync

source build/envsetup.sh

lunch aosp_bluejay-userdebug

m

cd ~/aosp/out/target/product/bluejay (contains all imgs like boot.img, system.img). i dont see vendor.img???

adb reboot bootloader

fastboot flashall -w
```

When it finishes, it remains at fastboot screen, so I click start. I goes to Google logo, then reboots to bootloader. My fastboot version is b4s4-0.4-7773694.

Does anyone know why it's rebooting to after Google logo? Is there a log that I can look at like dmesg or logcat?

I have built for emulator
lunch aosp_sdk_x86_64. it flash successfully.
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the google driver binaries (usually called vendor blobs).

https://developers.google.com/android/drivers

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download driver search your driver according your device and build number. https://developers.google.com/android/drivers
2. After download driver, extract driver and put on AOSP root folder.
3. Run this command on AOSP root folder.

> ./extract-google_devices-coral.sh

4. Here shows their terms and conditions. In last line shows

> Type "I ACCEPT" if you agree to the terms of the license:

5. Type I ACCEPT.
6. Then put these command one by one

> source build/envsetup.sh

> lunch aosp_bluejay-userdebug

> make

> adb reboot bootloader

> fastboot flashall -w